# Jquery selector can find hidden element ( display: none;), how to disable this case?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, hidden

I have Html code

```
<div id="demo" style="display:none;">Test demo</div>
```

and javascript:

```
$("#demo");
```

It will be selected, but I want to div with id = "demo", can not be selected because it's hidden.

Thank's

Comment: Not clear what requirement is. What do you mean by "can not be selected"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand correctly and you only want to select `#demo` if it's not hidden, use `$('#demo:visible')`. Some helpful resources are https://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/ and https://api.jquery.com/hidden-selector/

Comment: You don't need to use `:visible` to selecting element when you have it id.

Comment: @Mohammad I  know that. I believe OP *only wants to select `#demo` if it isn't hidden*. `$('#demo')` will always select `#demo`. `$('#demo:visible')` will only select `#demo` if it's visible or not hidden.

Answer (score 0):

For selecting hidden use `$(':hidden#demo')`

For selecting Visible use `$(':visible#demo')`

Comment: why `.val`? it's not a form element

Comment: @PatrickHund .val was for getting the value of div. IF you just want to select the element.Check the updated code

Comment: You don't use `$.val()` to get the "value" of a div, that's for inputs. You would use `$.html()` or `$.text()`